# Recreate the code without list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, for-loop, list-comprehension

I am learning about list comprehension therefore i would like to recreate the code without list comprehension.

The code is the following:

```py
items=[x for x in input().split(",")]
items.sort()
print (items)
```

This is how i recreated it:

```py
print ("Enter comma seperated words: ")
userinput = input ().split(",")
words = []
for i in range (len(userinput)):
    words.append(userinput)
    words.sort()
print (words)
```

I expect the output should be in alphabetical order but it does not.

Comment: BTW, the list-comprehension in the first example doesn't do anything useful (as `x` is not used), so you can just put `items = input().split(",")` and you'll get identical behaviour.

Comment: I have unindented words.sort() but still the result is not in alphabetical order.

Comment: You wanna do `words.append(userinput(i))`, because your recreated result will look like `[['foo', 'bar']]` instead of `['foo', bar']` which is what it looks like in the list comprehension

Comment: Problem is, is that `input.split(',')` returns an array, and what you're doing in `words.append(userinput)` is appending an entire array into an array (thus nesting it). `words.sort()` doesn't sort nested arrays.

Comment: @Dai It doesn't matter if `words.sort()` is unindented or not, it just means that the list is sorted through every iteration of the loop instead of after the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say our input is this...

```
userinput = 'foo,bar'
```

Using the list comprehension code...

```
items=[x for x in userinput.split(",")]
items.sort()
print (items)
Output becomes: `['bar', 'foo']`
```

However, if we use your recreated code..

```
userinput = userinput.split(',')
words = []
for i in range (len(userinput)):
    words.append(userinput)
    words.sort()
print (words)
Output becomes: `[['foo', 'bar']]
```

Why is this?

When the line `userinput = userinput.split(',')` is run, `userinput` now becomes `['foo', 'bar']`. 
Therefore, when `words.append(userinput)` is run, what it is actually doing is saying `words.append(['foo', 'bar'])`, and thus you are appending a list into a list meaning that `words = [['foo', 'bar']]`.

`words.sort()` will not sort nested lists within itself, therefore, your list isnt sorted.

Therefore the fix is to append each element of userinput into words instead of appending userinput as a list into words.

```
userinput = userinput.split(',')
words = []
for i in range (len(userinput)):
    words.append(userinput[i])
    words.sort()
print (words)
Output becomes: ['bar', 'foo']
```